# Transpose data in SQL with new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have a data like:

```
id maths phy chem 
1   50   60   21
2   60   80   22
3   80   90   23
```

Now I want it to look like:

```
sub   1   2   3
math 50  60  80 
phy  60  80  90
chem 21  22  23
```

my code:

```
select *
  from mrks
    pivot
(
  max(maths) 
  for id in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv
```

however I'm facing 2 issues

1. I am not able to transpose chem and phy values
2. Not able to group maths, phy and chem under subj

Comment: What do you expect to happen if someone inserts the row (4, 75, 77, 81)?

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server, you can unpivot with `cross apply`, then pivot using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    col,
    max(case when id = 1 then val end) col1,
    max(case when id = 2 then val end) col2,
    max(case when id = 3 then val end) col3
from mytable t
cross apply (values ('maths', maths), ('phy', phy), ('chem', chem)) p(col, val)
group by col
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=26998646e432b38832be4671d265bfc0)**:

```
col   | col1 | col2 | col3
:---- | ---: | ---: | ---:
chem  |   21 |   22 |   23
maths |   50 |   60 |   80
phy   |   60 |   80 |   90
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `PIVOT` on multiple columns, you can achieve the desired output by using `UNION` as following.

```
SELECT 'Math' AS Sub,*
FROM (SELECT id ,maths FROM mrks) t
PIVOT(MAX(maths) FOR id IN ([1], [2], [3])) piv

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Phy' AS Sub,*
FROM (SELECT id,phy FROM mrks) t
PIVOT(MAX(phy) FOR id IN ([1], [2], [3])) piv

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Chem' AS Sub,*
FROM (SELECT id,chem FROM mrks) t
PIVOT(MAX(chem) FOR id IN ([1], [2], [3])) piv
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also work

```
DECLARE @tble TABLE (id INT, maths INT, phy INT, chem INT)
INSERT INTO @tble VALUES
(1,50,60,21),(2,60,80,22),(3,80,90,23);

select * from(
SELECT ID,maths AS Scores, 'maths' as Subjects FROM @tble
UNION
SELECT ID,phy AS Scores, 'phy' as Subjects FROM @tble
UNION
SELECT ID,chem AS Scores, 'chem' as Subjects FROM @tble  
  ) s
PIVOT
(
  MIN(Scores) 
  FOR id IN ([1], [2], [3])
) piv
```